# Convert Date Format

Tags: php

I have a moodle installation in which there is a column in mdl_user table called firstaccess whose type is bigint(10) and contains date in following format  **1266839570**.

I am writing a query for accessing users according to date filters. For e.g. i want to check which users firstaccess is greater than '2010-04-12'. How can i convert the date? These two date formats are different. I think firstaccess is unix timestamp. Should i change the '2010-04-12' into unix timestamp or there is a way to convert firstaccess i.e 1266839570 to yyyy-mm-dd format.

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unix timestamp in php with the `mktime()` function, then simply put it in your query.
MySQL has a `date_format()` function, that can format dates however you like, but I'm not sure if it works with bigints. You'd better go with the `mktime`.

Answer (score 1):

date() and mktime() are functions to concert from unix timestamp and back.
You can convert your dates in either way

Comment: sharpnel can you give the example how to use mktime because mktime has following syntax:
mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year,is_dst)

but my date is in following format: 1266839570

Comment: @Pankaj **date()** is used to format timestamps. date(). and example is available at the manual page

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can write your query using a timestamp. Eg.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE firstaccess >= TIMESTAMP('2010-04-12')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what form the date in your form is, but you can easily convert it to a timestamp (if it already isn't one) using [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php). For example:

```
$mytimestamp=mktime(0,0,0, $month, $day, $year);
```

Then just add it to your query:

```
$myQuery= "SELECT whatever FROM sometable WHERE " . $mytimestamp . ">=firstaccess";
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Paul Peelen, my answer is a MySQL query. I'm going the other way, though, and converting first access into a date.
Using the date information in your problem:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(firstaccess), '%Y-%m-%d') > '2010-04-12';
```